# Soap Request Error in Websphere Portal

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

The scenario is,
We created a Webservice (say *WS1*) using **WebExperience factory V8.0.0.2** and the **websphere application server is V8.0.0.10**. The *WS1* has an operation which calls another webservice (say *WS2*) for some authentication. All are soap services. When testing this scenario locally we were able to invoke the underlying webservice *WS2* and was able to get the response. 
I deployed it in *Webphere Portal*, wp_profile, but when I called the service *WS1* it is showing some SOAP error. The error is happening when *WS1* invokes *WS2*. We are using **Portal 8.0** and the **Application Server version is 8.0.0.10.**
*I changed the class loading to parent last in the application module*. But it is still showing the error.
Stack trace is given

```
    Category: bowstreet.system.server.logging.event.criterion.abnormal
    Priority: ERROR
    Msg:      Component:    SERVICE
    Caught an exception processing a message style web service call.
        The associated exception is: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.MsgProvider.processMessage(MsgProvider.java:141)
        at com.bowstreet.axis.providers.WebAppMSGProvider.processMessage(WebAppMSGProvider.java:46)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
        at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1214)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:926)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1023)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3703)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: Error in method BatchInvoke_al. Error in method getDetail_ws.invoke.  Error in method getDetail_ws.invokeInternal. javax/xml/soap/MessageFactory.newInstance(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/xml/soap/MessageFactory;
        at com.bowstreet.axis.WebAppRPCInterface.aMethod(WebAppRPCInterface.java:68)
        ... 41 more
```

Can anyone help me on this issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WARs you're deploying to the two servers (working and non-working) are different one is dev mode WAR built by deploying from designer (which is a dual mode WAR that supports the WEF standalone servlet mode plus portlets) and the other an exported portlet WAR.   If so, then the two WARs would have different sets of JARs (less jars in the portlet WAR which defers to portal for some of those APIs).

Please cross checked the module class loader in the application module.
**saaj-api.jar** will be missing in dev mode war bulid.
Remove the **saaj-api.jar** from the **lib** and export the war and deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the libraries using in the Applications?
Please check whether any dependant jar files is loading twice after starting the application.
You can view the loaded class files in the application server console.